# Human vs. machine energy expenditures

Tags: energy, electric-circuits

I've read that a typical human-powered bicycle power generator generates around 100W. For the same amount of effort, the bike travels probably around 20k/h on a road. Does that mean it requires 100Wh for a ~70kg load to travel 20km? If so, does it mean that a 70kg-machine with wheels (e.g., a RC car) requires 125Wh (100Wh / 0.8 assuming 80% motor efficiency) to travel 20km? But how well can one translate the energy human expends when cycling into energy a machine with wheels expends?

Comment: The human body has an efficiency of about 0.25, so you'll burn energy at a rate of 400 Watt to deliver that 100 Watt to your bike.

Comment: @CountIblis Yes, but if a human rider burns 400W to travel at 20kph, will a machine only need 125W to travel at 20kph given that motors have an efficiency of around 80%?

Comment: Yes, that's right